# For $n\ge 3$, $m(n)=$ maximum points within/on the boundary of a regular $n$-gon of side $1$, dist between any two points $>1$.

Tags: geometry

> For $n\ge 3$, $m(n)=$ maximum points within/on the boundary of a regular $n$-gon of side $1$, dist between any two points $>1$. Find all $n$: $m(n) = n-1$.

I didn't really try solving this question but I was thinking about it and thought distance formula would have to be used here.
For example if $n=3$, we'll have a triangle. Let us assume that one of the vertices of the triangle lies on the origin.
Let $(x,y)$ be any point lying inside or on the boundary of the triangle. Now, the maximum distance of that point from the origin will have to be one of the other vertices. Hence, the distance between any two points in an equilateral triangle of side length $1$ is never greater than $1$.
Hence, $m(3)=0$.

If $n=4$, you'll get a square of side length $1$. The maximum distance between two points in such a square will be $\sqrt2$ (along the diagonal). But how do we calculate the number of points in a square where dist $>1$ and $\le\sqrt2$?

And how do we generalize this for an $n$-gon?

Comment: The question is unclear. Please reformulate it in a more verbose way. Moreover, as presented, it looks a very artificial stand-alone question : is it  a question asked in a competition ?

Comment: One thing is certain : you need the formula for the diagonal lengths of a regular n-gon as you can find it established in the answer to this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/687371

Comment: I'm so sorry if it's unclear, the max length was 150 characters...anyhoo here's the question again- "For any natural number n>= 3, let m(n) denote the maximum number of points lying within or on the boundary of a regular n-gon of side length 1 such that the distance between any two of the points is greater than 1. Find all n such that m(n) = n-1. Also, I don't think it was asked in any competition, I came across this question in a discussion forum ..

Comment: Can you guide me as to how to use that formula? Because the question says number of points